# How to make bitcoin hard fork

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin

I am exploring bitcoin source code for some time and have successfully created a local bitcoin network with new genesis block.
Now i am trying to understand the process of hard forks (if i am using wrong terms here, i am referring to the one where the blockchain is split instead of mining a new genesis).
I am trying find this approach in BitcoinCash source code, but haven't got anywhere so far except the checkpoints.

```
//UAHF fork block.
  {478558, uint256S("0000000000000000011865af4122fe3b144e2cbeea86"
          "142e8ff2fb4107352d43") }
```

So for i understand that the above checkpoint is responsible for the chain split. But i am unable to find the location in source code where this rule is enforced, i.e. the code where it is specified to have a different block than bitcoin after block number 478558.
Can anyone set me into the right direction here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is not a specific rule that you put in the source code that says "this is where the fork starts". The checkpoints are just for bootstrapping a new node, they are checked to make sure the right chain is being downloaded and verified.

A hard fork by definition is just a change in consensus rules. By nature, if you introduce new consensus-breaking rules, any nodes that are running Bitcoin will reject those blocks which are incompatible and as soon as one block is rejected (and mined on the other chain) you will now have different chains.

As a side note, you should probably change the default P2P ports and P2P message headers in `chainparams.cpp` so it doesn't try to connect with other Bitcoin nodes.